# Python mysql string substitution not working

Tags: python, mysql, string-substitution

I've been using this syntax with great success in python mysql.

```
search = "O'%"   # find names like O'Brien or O'Connell...

cursor.execute ("""
   select userid
      from usertab
    where name like %s
""" , (search))
```

But sometimes I need to build my sql string before I execute it like the following, but the substitution technique is different than above and doesn't work in all cases.

```
search = "O'%"   # find names like O'Brien or O'Connell...

sql = """
   select userid
      from usertab
    where name like '%s'
""" % (search)

cursor.execute(sql)
```

How can I achieve the same kind of string substitution that works well in the first example, without executing the cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MySQLdb` [uses](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/030d175754fb6b296786449e124dfc86a79e79b2/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L183) the connection's [`literal()`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.connections.Connection-class.html#literal) method to [escape](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/030d175754fb6b296786449e124dfc86a79e79b2/MySQLdb/connections.py#L264) the arguments, so you could use:

```
sql = """
   select userid
      from usertab
    where name like %s
""" % cursor.connection.literal(search)
```

Comment: that works... I want to sit on this for day to see what others might suggest... I'm curious how others approach the same problem.

Comment: this solution becomes cumbersome when you have several substitutions.

Comment: what do you mean with several substitutions? you can just pass a tuple, and each element will be escaped individually: `"select ... where a = %s and b = %s and ..." % literal((a, b, ...))`

Comment: ooo.... interesting.  How can I use the short name literal as in your example instead of cursor.connection.literal ?

Comment: I just forgot to add that part, but you could just use `literal = cursor.connection.literal` to make it available as `literal` if that makes it easier (or `connection.literal`, no real need to get it from cursor...)